# How to get driving distance between two lat/longs in Windows Phone 8.1 Universal App

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, bing-maps, windows-phone-8.1, win-universal-app

I've definitely seen some REST APIs out there that can do this but I'm sure there's a WinRT/Windows Phone 8 Store App way of calculating driving distance (preferably with traffic) between two Geolocations points (lat/long).

I see ways of doing it by returning a map on the phone with the details, but I just want the distance information returned without going to a mapping UI or control.

This would preferably work on a tablet (WindowsRT) as well but Phone is the focus at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bing Maps REST API is the way to do it.

Here's [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701717.aspx) and [a sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg636957.aspx). You can find one way of how to use these with .NET [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819168.aspx).

Comment: I finally stumbled upon the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/dn631250.aspx) after trying a few different keywords.  It's only for Phone, though, so I'll have to use your suggestion for tablet.  Thanks!